# Need geocoding service to replace geocode.com service

Tags: batch, geocoding

I have used the geocode process at geocode.com for many years and now they are no longer doing this service so I'm looking for another service to help me with my geocoding.  I wanted to list out what I'm looking for and I wanted to see if anyone knows of another service that could provide me this information.  I'm looking for a batch geocoding process that I will need to run about 100,000 address once every year or so.

These are the fields that were returned from the previous process I used.

```
STD_ADDR -    Postal standard street address
STD_CITY -    Postal standard city name
STD_ST   -    Postal standard state abbreviation
STD_ZIP  -    Postal standard 5-digit ZIP code
STD_P4   -    Postal standard Plus4 code
STD_CR   -    Postal standard carrier route
MAT_ADDR -    Matched Address
MAT_CITY -    Matched City
MAT_ST   -    Matched State
MAT_ZIP  -    Matched ZIP code
MAT_LAT  -    Matched latitude (decimal degrees)
MAT_LON  -    Matched longitude (decimal degrees)
FIPS_ST  -    State FIPS code
FIPS_CTY -    County FIPS code
CEN_TRCT -    Census Tract
CEN_BLK  -    Census Block
FIPS_PLC -    FIPS Place
FIPS_MCD -    FIPS MCD Code
FIPS_MSA -    FIPS MSA Code
MAT_CENT -    Centroid Type Code
CBSA     -    CBSA Code
METROD   -    Metropolitan Division Code
MICROF   -    Micropolitan Flag
MAT_STAT -    Matchmaker Status Code
MAT_TYPE -    Match Type Code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/ with your own API key for batch geocoding but there are also the common restrictions if you don't want to pay for the service. (Just one addition in general : Outside the USA where you don't have tiger data you could use http://www.gisgraphy.com/ )

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  I will look into both options and report back.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a Tiger Geocoder on PostGIS to do all my geocoding. This approach has several advantages. The biggest that it is free and it is something that you own completely. You won't get surprised by any change in the license or terms of use. I'm not sure if you can get all the fields that the process you were using before will give you, but you should be able to figure out most of that from the Geocoder itself, and by using spatial joins. Here are some links that you might find useful.

http://www.peterstratton.com/2014/04/your-own-private-geocoder-using-postgis-and-ubuntu/

http://www.postgis.us/downloads/postgis20_tiger_cheatsheet.html

http://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html

Another set of options is using a commercial geocoder like Bing or Google Maps to do the geocoding. I haven't made much use of these, but at least for the Google Geocoder you cannot use the free geocoder if you are trying to geocode more than a certain number of addresses. One option (I am looking into this right now, but have never actually done it before) is to only a commercial geocoder for those addresses that can't be geododed accurately using the TIGER geocoder to get more accuracy, without having to pay extra money.

Comment: The first link is not working. And the website don't have any post now.

Answer (score -1):

Agree on Tiger Geocoder of PostGIS.

I recorded my experience on [system setup](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/17/Geocoding/) and [script](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/19/Script-workflow/) in my blog. It may save you some time to avoid some common mistakes.